# How to do ldap authentication in spring security 6

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, model-view-controller, spring-security

I am getting error while doing with all the existing methods for creating ldap authentication server using spring security 6

And cant even verify the data using the .ldif file given and grant authentication .I have an .ldif file and need the credentials authenticate against this file.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what errors are you getting? Have you read the (migration) documentation? Which dependencies are you using. So in short too little information to answer this.

Comment: Actually i created bean and methods according to the spring security 6 documentation but still I get unsatisfied dependency exception

Comment: Please **show** what you have done so far, don't describe. Show your configuration **and** the error stacktrace (the **full stacktrace**) that you get.